# Get target framework of .net assembly that has target framework < .net 4.0

Tags: .net, dll, frameworks, exe, .net-assembly

I would like to identify the target framework version of a .net assembly (dll or exe).
How can I do this, if the .net assembly has a target framework < .net 4.0 ?
It would be nice if there is a solution where I don't have to use external tools. I would prefer a solution that is based on Microsoft VS / PowerShell or Windows.
I would be so happy if you can help me with this.
Because right now I only know how to get the target framework version if the assembly has a target version >= .net 4.0. (In this case I just look inside the assembly's manifest and look at the TargetFrameworkAttribute)

thanks a lot

PhilOverflow

Comment: Assemblies don't target a framework version, they target a *runtime* version.  It will be 2.0.50727 and the [TargetFrameworkAttribute] will be missing.  Not at all obvious from your question why this is important, but the missing attribute is enough of a cue perhaps.  Or [use this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230176(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: <4.0 means it does not support target framework version feature. You should simply accept that fact.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom to load the Assembly and then inspected the returned Assembly's ImageRuntimeVersion, like:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(ada.FileName);
    string name = assembly.GetName();
    string clrVersion = assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;
```

I have successfully detected .NET 2 and .NET 4 assemblies from a .NET 4 executable using this technique, but not sure if it will work from a .NET 2 executable to detect .NET 4 assemblies.

Comment: This is a good idea to detect the runtime version. For me its more important to know the framework version of the assembly instead of the runtime version. But I thank you a lot that you want to help.